# Consecutive application threads and uncommitted data in Oracle

Tags: oracle, concurrency

Our application reads a record from an Oracle 'Event' table. When the event record exists we update the 'count' field of that record. If the record doesn't exist we insert it. So we want only 1 record for a particular event in the table.

The problem with this is probably quite predictable: one application thread will read the table, see the event is not there, insert the new event and commit. But before it commits a second thread will also read the table and see the event is not there. And then both threads will insert the event and we end up with 2 records for the same event.

I guess synchronizing access to this particular method in our application will prevent this problem, but what is the best option in Oracle to prevent this?  Will MERGE for example always prevent this problem?

Comment: Merge will secure it and for me it would be preferable solution. Securing it in application would make it save only for the aplication (not other applications possibly generating same events) but it would be definitely more code, less safe and slower.

Comment: Merge will not secure it, as it operates under exactly the same read consistency model as any other SQL statement, and in any case is not an atomic operation.

Comment: @Husqvik and David - those are two diametrically opposed answers :-) Actually, I assume David is right in saying that the problem would still exist, because even using MERGE the second MERGE query would not see the uncommitted change of the first MERGE (a.k.a read_committed isolation), right?

Comment: Of course assumed atomic statement, then it would be secured. Because one merge updating/inserting the row should lock the other merge until is finished so the second merge will use the actual data. Of course you need to have unique constraint which will secure the serializing to the event record.

Comment: @Husqvik, a merge by one session *that inserts a row* does not involve any lock that would stop another session issuing the same merge.

Comment: @Julius, I would have thought a unique constraint would be the right answer to this problem - what is stopping you from creating a unique constraint or unique index here?

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp, not the merge/insert but the unique/PK constraint. Just try it. If you have two sessions inserting the same value that is under unique/PK constraint the second session waits until you commit/rollback the first transaction. If the transaction is rolled back the second session succeeds if committed the second session fails on constraint violation. Of course with unique constraint it only applies if the value is not NULL.

Comment: @Husqvik, yes, a unique constraint is what I recommended already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialising access to the procedure that implements this functionality would be trivial to implement, using [DBMS_LOCK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lock.htm) to define and take an exclusive lock.

Serialising through SQL based methods is practically impossible, due to the read consistency model.

Comment: Update is always serialized as well as insert involving unique constraint.

Comment: Maybe there's a way of using unique constraints and of catching exceptions etc, and of course you'd want unique constraints in place to protect the data whenever possible. But providing an explicit serialisation mechanism in the API is trivial and very lightweight.

Comment: I didn't mention this in my question, but we only want one record per event_type (string) per day (date field). That would be hard to capture in a  unique constraint.

Comment: You can create a unique function-based index on (Trunc(my_date), event_type) -- that would do it.

Comment: And in this case it's even simpler, because you can create the event record for next day in advance, so it will be secured the row exists and you can have just simple UPDATE incrementing the counter consistently.

Comment: Marking this answer as accepted answer as it is the closest to the behavior we are looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTS (ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, COUNTER NUMBER NOT NULL);

MERGE INTO EVENTS
USING (SELECT ID, COUNTER FROM DUAL LEFT JOIN EVENTS ON EVENTS.ID = :EVENT_ID) SRC
ON (EVENTS.ID = SRC.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET COUNTER = SRC.COUNTER + 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID, COUNTER) VALUES (:EVENT_ID, 1);
```

Simple SQL securing single record for each ID and consistently increasing the counter no matter what application fires it or number of concurrent thread. You don't need to code anything at all and it's very lightweight as well.

It also doesn't produce any exception related to data consistency so you don't need any special handling.

UPDATE: It actually produces unique violation exception if both threads are inserting. I thought the second merge would switch to update, but it doesn't.

UPDATE: Just tested the same case on SQL Server and when executing in parallel and the record doesn't exist one MERGE inserts and the second updates.

Comment: Yes, as Tom Kyte explains here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:61865893444475 you do have to serialise if you want to avoid the potential for either data inconsistency or needing to handle errors thrown by unique constraints.